# Unable to extend LV file system in Ubuntu Server

Tags: lvm, resize2fs

I run a bare metal Ubuntu server with several VMs running in a KVM environment.  I want to increase the size of one VM from 50GB to 100GB.

[image: nextcloudph-lv]

I ran the following command to increase the nextcloudph-lv VM from 50GB to 100GB:

`sudo lvextend -L+50G /dev/ubuntu-vg/nextcloudph-lv`

The VM size increased as expected.

[image: nextcloudph after increase]

I then attempted to extend the LV file system using the following command:

`sudo resize2fs  /dev/ubuntu-vg/nextcloudph-lv`

The output I received is:

[image: Bad magic number error message]

Running the lsblk command results in:

[image: lsblk]

And /dev/mapper contains:

[image: dev mapper list]

This looks like a relatively simple process so I'm not sure where I've gone wrong.  This is the first time I'm trying to extend an LV and I'm stuck...

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

As suggested by A. Darwin, I ran the command "df -hT" which produced the following output:

[image: df -hT]

I can see the host VM "ubuntu--lv" with an ext4 file system but there is no reference to "nextcloudph--lv" or sda3 where all the VMs are located.

I'm not sure if it makes a difference but when I set up the VMs I first allocated the space using the "lvcreate -L ##G -n lv###### ubuntu-vg" command and then pointed Virtual Machine Manager to that storage pool when building the VM.

EDIT 2
Running "df hT" from within the nextcloudph-lv VM produces the following output:

[image: nextcloudph df -hT]

It's strange because there is a reference to a 48GB ext4 drive but it's located at "/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv".

EDIT 3

As requested by Vojtech Trefny, attached is the output from the command "lsblk -f"

[image: lsblk -f]

For clarity, the 84% used refers only to the ubuntu--lv VM.  There is still plenty of room left on the SSDs.

Comment: What kind of filesystem is that? Run df -hT or similar. If it’s xfs, you may need to run xfs_growfs (followed by the mount point) rather than resize2fs.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I ran the command "df -hT" and have posted the output above and included additional information on how I built the VMs using Virtual Machine Manager.

Comment: `df` shows only mounted devices, please use `lsblk -f`

Comment: Hi Vojtech Trefny , I've added the output from running the command "lsblk -f".  Thanks for your help with this!

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Noted.  This was my first post so I'll minimise the use of images in the future.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The LV doesn't seem to contain a file system directly, but probably is a whole disk image to the VM. In that case, you need to change the partition size and resize the file system from within the VM; alternatively, you can stop the VM, and treat the LV as whole disk using a partitioning tool, resize the data partition, then set up a loop device with an offset pointing to the enlarged partition and resize the file system within that.

Answer (score 0):

Run the command `sudo lvextend -L+50G /dev/ubuntu-vg/nextcloudph-lv` again, but rather than trying to resize after extending, resize within the `lvextend` command with `-r` so it will look like `sudo lvextend -L+51G -r /dev/ubuntu-vg/nextcloudph-lv`. (Maybe add an extra 1G so it attempts a new extend)

If you get the same error as above in your OP, then make sure the logical volume has a valid filesystem, if not, make it one e.g `mkfs.ext4 /dev/ubuntu-vg/nextcloudph-lv` and then try and resize again.

Comment: Well, your suggestions made sense so I gave them a try.  The first time I ran the lvextend command with the -r it gave an error complaining about the file system so I tried to add the ext4 fiel system but ultimately the entire VM crashed.  When I turn it on now I get the following fatal error:  "Boot failed:  not a bootable disk".  I'll rebuild the VM from scratch again and rebuild the entire server in the coming weeks so this doesn't happen again.

Comment: Do you still see the VM with `virsh list --all`? If you can see the VM, then the XML configs are probably there too so you can redefine it. What is the output of `lvs` and `lvscan`? Most importantly, you have your back ups. Right?

Comment: I have a backup so no worries.  I've already deleted the VM and am starting on a temporary rebuild.  I think the main issue I'm having is the way the entire server was configured so I plan to rebuild it again from scratch over an upcoming weekend so I don't run into these issues in the future.  Thanks again!